# how to insert current date in datetime field in mysql using java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am working on date time using Java. I am trying to insert the current date in MySQL. The data type for the table in database is datetime. When I am trying to insert the data, an exception is thrown

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

I want to insert current date in in that field.

Comment: You can use NOW() function of mysql.

Comment: Post the code that is doing the insert.

Comment: You need to format the date correctly if you are using concat sql, mysql format is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss, but before you concat queries be    aware.... better prepared statement

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended that you insert the current date using SQL rather than Java. To do so, use the MySQL `CURDATE()` function. Your query will look like this:

```
INSERT INTO orders (order_date, order_description)
     VALUES (CURDATE(), 'Jarlsberg Cheese');
```

Note that CURDATE() gives you the date only. If you want the time you need to use `NOW()`, or `CURTIME()`:

- `NOW()`: Gives you the date and time, e.g. 2014-11-11 12:45:34.
- `CURDATE()`: Gives you the date only, e.g. 2014-11-11.
- `CURTIME()`: Gives you the time only, e.g. 12:45:34.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NOW() function of mysql. NOW() returns the current date and time.

Hope it will help you.
Happy coding.